# Combined Highstock , want to set the proper zoom object

Tags: zooming, highcharts

I have a highstock chart which hosts a stacked column + a spline line . I have some issues with the preview shown at the bottom : it is neither for the stacked column nor for the spline line , and I want to set it to one of these (preferably the stacked column ) . From what I am guessing, the highstock renders a preview for a combination of them, but i am not sure. Please help!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navigator: {
                baseSeries: 'spline',
                height: 35
           },

'spline' is the ID of the series i want to render in the preview